# What pressure can 'normal' consumer-packaged chip withstand?

Tags: specifications

I thought I'd be able find this easily via google, but apparently not, so: 
What pressure can 'normal' consumer-packaged chip withstand?

(To give a specific example, say the OMAP4430)

I'm presuming it's complex parts like this that would break first under high pressure, instead of simpler passive parts, or the PCB itself.

I'm also assuming the pressure is applied hydrostatically - so air gaps under components, provided they are not completely sealed, will be the same pressure as the external pressure.

Comment: So this is like being inside a high pressure air chamber, and not like the pressure of a heatsink mounted on top of the IC?

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be much more concerned about components that have internal cavities, such as electrolytic capacitors and batteries, that are sealed and rely on internal pressure to maintain structure. IC's are solid throughout and I wouldn't be nearly so concerned about them.

Comment: Are they actually solid throughout?  The silicon has bonding wires to it from the pins, and then the black plastic fills in all the space between these wires and touches the silicon?

Comment: Maybe, but electrolytic capacitors are filled with electrolyte, which presumably gives them some strength? I suppose the same cannot be said for any lithium battery chemistries though?

Comment: @endolith: Yes. With the exception of UV-erasable chips with an obvious transparent window (and which no one seems to make nowadays), every IC I've ever broken has no air bubbles -- black plastic completely fills the space not occupied by the bonding wires and the leadframe and the silicon chip itself.